# How to make relationships on two tables using fields that are not primary keys in both tables

Tags: php, laravel

i have no better way to explain this, this is what i want to do
i want to make a one to many relationship between a students table and a students marks table, but i want the students' registration number to relate the tables yet the students' registration number is neither a primary key in any of the two tables.
This is my students table
[students table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfmZi.jpg)
this is my students results table
[student results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJGml.jpg)
i have tried to look every where on how to do this but i have failed.
please dont be hash am a newbie
Please help me, am a laravel starter building a school project needed soon.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Show us the tables, and the code that you have so far

Comment: check my last answer please... Fabricio i need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Mark model.
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        Student::class,
        'registration_number' //Field name in the student_marks table
        'registration_number' //Field name in the students table
    );
}

//Student model
public function marks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(
        Mark::class,
        'registration_number', //Field name in the student_marks table
        'registration_number', //Field name in the students table
    );
}
```

Detail information about relationship defining;
https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html

Comment: thank you sir... let me try that right away... thank you

Comment: please check my last answer and see my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach($marks as $mark)
                                                <tr class="item{{$mark->id}}">
                                                    <td>{{ App\Students_mark::find($mark->id)->marks_for('Name_of_Student') }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$mark->regno}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$mark->course_unit_id}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$mark->term_id}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$mark->c_w_marks}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$mark->e_o_t_marks}}</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button class="show-modal btn btn-sm btn-success" data-id="{{$mark->id}}" data-name="{{$mark->regno}}" data-abbrev="{{$mark->course_unit_id}}" data-level="{{$mark->term_id}}" data-lecturer="{{$mark->c_w_mrks}}">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View</button>
                                                        <button class="edit-modal btn btn-sm btn-info" data-id="{{$mark->id}}" data-name="{{$mark->regno}}" data-abbrev="{{$mark->course_unit_id}}" data-level="{{$mark->term_id}}" data-lecturer="{{$mark->c_w_mrks}}">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button>
                                                        <button class="delete_data btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{{$mark->id}}" data-name="{{$mark->regno}}">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
```

I tried Mutas' Relationship code and i hope it works but now am having another issue, i am trying to loop through the Students marks and then get the name of the student using the relation below 
students registration model

```
        public function marks(){
        return $this->hasMany(
            Students_mark::class,
            'regno',
            'RegNo'
        );
    }
```

students marks table

```
        public function marks_for(){
        return $this->belongsTo(
            StudentsReg::class,
            'regno',
            'RegNo'
        );
    }
```

hope you understand me, am looking for a better way to explain this but i have failed!